# Cost sensitive analysis in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn

Is there a scikit-learn method/class analogous to the **MetaCost** algorithm implemented in Weka or other utilities to perform const sensitive analysis ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't. Some classifiers offer `class_weight` and `sample_weight` parameters, but those are just optimized implementations over oversampling and undersampling, not MetaCost.

Comment: Is `class_weight` a param that can set cost in each class? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier

Comment: `class_weight` can take `'balanced'` in which case sklearn will determine the proportion of each class in the train set and apply that as cost. It can be `None`, in which case the algorithm will be trained without cost sensitive learning. And it can also take a dictionary of class: cost pairs, eg, `class_weight = {1:1, 2:1, 3:10}`. In this case the cost of misclassification of an observation of class 3 is 10 times higher than misclassifying the other 2 classes.